# Enable drag and drop for File Download control and attachment links from View control

Tags: jquery, dojo, xpages

I have the following request:

Allow users to drag and drop attachments from File Download Control and Attachments links from View control into a Memo document opened in their Notes client without saving attachments locally and then uploading then manually.

I need to enable this for:

1. An XPage that contains document details and a file download control
2. View Control with a computed column, that contains a Repeat Control with links to each attached document
3. Users with IE8 (corporate standard at the moment)

I found this link: [OpenNTF XSnippets](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=drag-and-drop-attachment-links-from-file-download-control-to-operating-system-to-download) but only works in Chrome and just allows drag and drop to file system.

I'm open to any other solution but I cannot install anything on users machines.

Regards,

Pablo Solano

Answer (score 3):

Pablo. Drag & Drop is a browser function. It has nothing to do with the backend. If O'er doesn't support it...
... You are in ugly hack territory.
I know 3 potential approaches:
- an ActiveX control
- a Flash applet
- deploy Chrome frame
The last one would be best, users still start/see IE8 but you could use all of HTML5. Unfortunately it is also the option IT resists most

Comment: You are right this is an ugly hack territory and maybe a just "nice to have feature". Customer states they already have this option from current Notes database. My role at this point is trying to find an alternative option for them and avoid the manual process of detaching and attaching files into emails. I found that by making right click on Attachment link, selecting "Copy as Shortcut" and then using "Attach File" from Notes client they can paste URL from clipboard on "Create Attachment" dialog and this will work. I'm going to give a try with mailto option as well.

Comment: Are you aware of any ActiveX control or a Flash applet I can take a look at?

Comment: So your task is to allow them to send attachments found in a web application (you control) via eMail? How about a link/button next to the attachment "eMail this" that would compose an eMail directly in the browser with a send and a save as draft option

Comment: ActiveX: The iNotes attachment ActiveX, but we never documented/supported it outside iNotes, so you need to find out yourself. Flash: http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx